# Logic Pro X Movie Sound

Tags: software, logic-pro

I am creating a new score for a commercial. I've imported the movie into the project, which also import its sound. I went to `File->Project Settings->Movie` Tab and I muted the movie volume for the movie track. When I export the video, via `File->Export` audio to movie, the original track is playing along with my stuff. I've tried unmuting the track and lowering the volume to zero, but to no avail. Any other possible solutions?

Comment: A sloppy workaround would be to remove the audio from the original movie altogether in a separate video editing program, then use the silent version of the video in Logic. But you're right, it seems like there should be a way to do this all in Logic. (I don't work with movies in Logic myself, so I don't know.)

Comment: Yup, that is an option. I'm hoping that it's not the only option because this is actually an assignment for my students and they would have to redo their entire projects :/

Comment: I can't post a full answer at this time, but here are some discussions on other forums about bouncing without the original video's audio. (They're both for older versions of Logic, but hopefully they'll still be helpful.) http://www.logicprohelp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=260283 http://www.logic-users-group.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2144

Comment: Dude...genius! Their explanation is a little unclear. Basically, in the picture that they show, the "Sound (2 channels..." part should be unhighlighted. If it is highlighted, then it includes the sound from the original movie. Thanks dude. Please post an answer so that you can get some credit...sorry for the delay.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you export your movie, immediately before Logic X bounces your audio, you are presented with a dialog window that looks like this:

[image]

This window lists all of the audio tracks that are found in the original movie that you are editing. (Usually, this will be one stereo track.) **Any tracks that are selected when you click "OK" on this window will be included in the movie that is ultimately exported *in addition* to the audio you created in Logic.**

This means that in order to export the video with only the sounds you created in Logic, you need to **deselect everything in this dialog window.** You can easily deselect all of the items at once by clicking inside the table on the window, but not on any of the rows listing tracks. In this answer's example, you could click on any row except the first one that is highlighted in blue.

Once you've deselected all of the tracks, the window will look like this:

[image]

When you click "OK" on the dialog window at this point, the movie will be exported using only the audio you created in Logic X. The movie's original audio will be removed from your exported movie.

Comment: Sources: http://logicprohelp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=260283 and http://logic-users-group.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2144